# JavaScripts, AJAX, PHP: can't set field values after getting json string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Here is my code for product.php:

```
<script src="../Scripts/product.js"></script>
<form id="frmAddEditProduct" name="frmAddEditProduct" method="post" action="addproduct.php">
  <select class="form-control"  id="companyname" name="companyname">
    <option value"xyz">XYZ</option>
  </select>
  <input type="onlytext" class="form-control" name="productname" id="productname" placeholder="Product Name" required  />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="productlength" id="productlength" placeholder="Product Length" required  />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="productwidth" id="productwidth" placeholder="Product Width" required  />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="productheight" id="productheight" placeholder="Product Height" required  />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="productdeckle" id="productdeckle" placeholder="Deckle" required  />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="productcutting" id="productcutting" placeholder="Cutting" required  />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="productprice" id="productprice" placeholder="Price" required  />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" />
</form>

<a onclick='EditProduct(id is passed);' href='#'>Edit</a>
```

Here is my code for editproduct.php

```
<?php 
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could Not Connect to DB: ".mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db("proshell", $connection) or   die("Could Not Connect to DB: ".mysql_error());

    $json = array();
    $ID = $_GET['Id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product where Id=$ID");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $row_array['Id'] = $row[0];
         $row_array['Company'] = $row[1];
         $row_array['Name'] = $row[2];
         $row_array['Length'] = $row[3];
         $row_array['Width'] = $row[4];
         $row_array['Height'] = $row[5];
         $row_array['Deckle'] = $row[6];
         $row_array['Cutting'] = $row[7];
         $row_array['Price'] = $row[8];          

         array_push($json, $row_array);
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Here is my code for product.js

```
function EditProduct(id) {
    //RemoveValidation();
    $('#status').html('');
    var userid = $('#id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'editproduct.php',
        data: { "Id": id},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "Error") {
                $('#companyname').val(data.Company);
                $('#productname').val(data.Name);
                $('#productlength').val(data.Length);
                $('#productwidth').val(data.Width);
                $('#productheight').val(data.Height);
                $('#productdeckle').val(data.Deckle);   
                $('#productcutting').val(data.Cutting); 
                $('#productprice').val(data.Price);                 
                $('#productname').focus();
            }
            else {
                $('#status').attr("style", "color:Red;");
                $('#status').html("There was some error while getting data please refresh page and try again.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

here after clicking on Edit button in product.php It comes to javascript function and it goes in to if condition when i watch my code in console of firefox it also give me string as response like this:

```
[{"Id":"1","Company":"Chintan Co.","Name":"Chintan's Box","Length":"7","Width":"8","Height":"9","Deckle":"17","Cutting":"18","Price":"99"}]
```

In if condition of EditProduct.php method
if I do like this: $('#productlength').val(data.Length);
then textbox shows nothing but if I do like this $('#productlength').val(data.length); then it shows me the length of the json array but I can't set any field.

So help me out here please.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping the data object in a needless array.

So in the javascript you would actually need to change `data.Company` to `data[0].Company` and similar for other properties.

I would suggest you get rid of the extra array in php

Instead of `array_push($json, $row_array);` just send `$row_array`

ALso note your php is very insecure using `mysql` extension which is deprecated and not sanitizing input for query

Comment: also add `dataType:'json'` to `$ajax`

Comment: how to do that $row_array stuff?

Comment: `echo json_encode($row_array)` . Should also define `$row_array` in case no data returned in query

Comment: Please use browser dev tools console to check for errors. This is your most important first line of troubleshooting javascript

Comment: well you should have seen errors and mentioned them in question. They tell you a lot

Comment: there were no errors. It didn't show anything in console except json string. Now still Name i.e. Productname doesn't work